# jQuery change text with function return value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to change the text of each div with the class "container".
I have a function test1, which will call after a click on a button.
This function should change the text with return values of function test2. but the text will not be changed. `alert(result)` shows the correct text which I expect. How can I solve this issue?

```
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>


function test1() {
   $( ".container" ).each(function() { 
      $( ".container" ).text(test2('MyValue'));
   })
}

function test2(value) {  
   $.getJSON("ajax.php", {
      value: value
   }, function(result) {
        alert(result);
        return result;  
   })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you're actually parsing the json that gets returned.

Comment: , function(result) {
        $( ".container" ).text(result);
   })

Comment: The `test2` function doesn't return anything because your return statement is happening inside a callback on the `getJSON` function.

Comment: @Herohtar -> what does this mean? how can I return the value of `getJSON` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the text until the AJAX is done.. [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are a good solution..

```
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>
<div class="container">Some text</div>


function test1() {
   test2('myValue').then(res=>$( ".container" ).text(res))
}

function test2(value) { 
   return new Promise(done=>
   $.getJSON("ajax.php", {
      value: value
   }, function(result) {
        done(result); 
   }));
}
```